# Compiz process is killing the CPU 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unity, compiz

I have already seen other posts about this problem, however, none of the solutions worked for me. The compiz process is simply killing the CPU, although I am not even using the GUI and only remotely connected to this virtual machine via SSH. The virtual machine is created using VmWare.

The reason we haven't installed 16.10 is because the security updates kept crashing the GUI.

The question is: How to make sure that compiz doesn't waste all my CPU resources?

[image]

Comment: And what is your question, actually?

Comment: @MarcVanhoomissen I have added the question explicitly. How to make sure that compiz doesn't go crazy and waste half of my CPU resources?

Comment: When running a VM you're using the virtualized hardware, not the real one. By definition it's limited.

Comment: "it is limited" doesn't mean that just the GUI should use 90% of the CPU resources